# Show [post_title] in content of Wordpress post?

Tags: wordpress

Just wanted to show the title of a Wordpress post. I've tried  with no success. Pretty new to this.

Comment: show what code you've tried and what's the error?

Comment: Sorry, included the code in the original post but it didn't show up. I tried (w/o brackets):
[<?php echo get_the_title( $post_id); ?>]

Comment: you can try to put it on your single php or in content loop / single  ( loop.php , content.php ).. without $post_id

Comment: Thanks. Not all pages for me would need to have that output displayed. Any ideas for how to add it to only a select group of pages?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, I hope this will help you.

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

and if  you want to add custom post type, in that case you need to add `WP_Query();` function to get the data like:

```
<?php

// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();
} else {
    // no posts found
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for displaying post title in specific pages either you can write:

`<?php get_the_title($post_id);?>`

into that page's template file or you can make a custom file in templates folder and add this code:

`<?php
if (is_page( 'Page Title' ) ):
  get_the_title($post_id);
endif;
?>`

and include this to all of your pages.. you can check for multiple pages by using OR condition in if statement.